# grunt is changing the paths of files defined in the Protractor Configuration file

Tags: javascript, protractor, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-jshint

i'm integrating my protractor tests in to grunt and i'm facing different situation with grunt.. when grunt running my configuration file it is searching for the files by changing the location.

Eg:

My file location i mentioned the path of the TestData file like

`c:/workspace/ProjectName/TestData/filename.ext`

so i written in my configuration file like

`../../TestData/file.extn` it is working as expected when running the configuration file

but when running with grunt it is using the same path searching like

`C:/TestData/file.extn`  means it is skipping 2 folders and it is starting search for the files from the grunt file location.

can someone help me in this.

Comment: how do you start tests? from IDE or command line terminal?

Comment: Will run in from command line